# How to see whether contact or journey data attribute was chosen?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Using either contact or journey data can be critical when using decision splits. But how can I find out whether a contact or journey data attribute was chosen, if attributes have the same name? The view only provides the attribute name, not from which source it was taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct the details of an attribute in a decision split is limited when viewing in an active Journey.  If you view the same decision split in the draft of the Journey you'll be able to see the path for each attribute.

See the example below where one path selects the emailaddress attribute from the Journey data (in this case a data extension) and the second selects Email from the contact synchronized data extension from SF CRM.

[image]

Comment: How do I get to this view? If I select a decision split in a Draft Journey, a pane shows up on the left hand side, but it does not show something like "PATH: JOURNEY DATA >", it just shows the names of the paths plus the criterium and the criterium only shows the attribute name (plus operator and value).

Comment: Does an Edit button show up in your UI to click into each attribute?

Comment: Yes, on the right hand side. From left to right: Path name, Condition, Edit button.

Comment: When you click into Edit do you see each field in the filter criteria section and a pencil icon on the right?  If you click that pencil icon it'll show you the path.

Comment: Clicking the pencil icon was the missing link. Thank you!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you can only see the path for the attribute on the left-hand side of the filter comparison. It is important when you select the option "Add an attribute to compare" at the bottom. If your Contact Data model includes the same attribute name for more than one data extension and this name is used on the right-hand side of the comparison, it will not be possible to assess which attribute is used.